# h:outputLink target doesn't work propely in case of multiple session

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have child window which has a hyperlink. On click of hyperlink i have to redirect to parent window. I'm using JSF's h:outputLink command -

```
<f:view>
<hx:scriptCollector 
    ....
    <h:form 
    ....
        <h:dataTable
            <h:column id="column1">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{pc_x.renderMacView}">                         
                    <h:outputLink target="main" id="detail" value="/abc/xyz.jsp" >
                        <f:param id="xId" name="xId" value="#{refId}"/>
                        <h:outputText id="textXId" value="#{refId}"/>
                    </h:outputLink>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:column> 
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</hx:scriptCollector>
```

Suppose i have two parent window (P1 and P2) with two different session (S1 and S2 respectively) open. If i try to open child window from P2 and click on hyperlink, it redirects to P1 window. This behavior is very inconsistent. How can i ensure that hyperlink on each child window updates to their respective parent window ? I tried giving target="_parent" but it replaces the child window on which i've hyperlink. We might have to target parent's parent window.

Comment: You should include relevant parts about the window, if I understand the same code is openned twice in browser?

Comment: I wonder how can you have 2 sessions in the same browser and having no problems between them (or probably you've discovered a leak in your application).

Comment: @Luiggi - I'm opening two browser with different session using IE New session window concept (noframemerging)

Comment: @Alex - just to explain you bit more, suppose i'm working on something in P1 and then i launched a new browser P2 with different session and now i have open a child window from P2 which has a hyperlink, when i click on hyperlink it redirects to P1 whereas ideally it should have redirected to P2 because parent ofr this child window was P2

Comment: `target` are for `frames`... Are you using frames?

Comment: @Alex- yes i'm using frame.

Comment: You should post more code, I think we will understand better, or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be nice!

Comment: @Alex - I've added some more code, it might help you understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode the sessionID into the target name, for example

```
target="main#{request.session.id}"
```

But I doubt that you can make multiple sessions from the same browser work correctly. Many have tried ...